Initiate RTK Query polling inside middleware
I have a Redux store middleware that listens to an action coming from one Redux slice and as a result I'd like to trigger polling against another (RTK Query) API slice endpoint, until the returned data contains the result I need.
All the examples I've seen (also here on SO) are based on useQuery Hooks that have a built-in skip mechanism, and rely on React rendering to manage the "infinite loop" thing.
What's the best practice on achieving something similar without React Hooks?
I'm currently doing something like this, which seems very manual:
// Check and validate action.payload...

// Optimistic update
storeAPI.dispatch(
  myApiSlice.util.updateQueryData(...)
)

const poll = async () => {
  const resultPromise = storeAPI.dispatch(
    myApiSlice.endpoints.myEndpoint.initiate({params}, {forceRefetch: true})
  )
  const {data, isError, isSuccess} = await resultPromise
  // Validate response...
  setTimeout(poll, DELAY)
}
setTimeout(poll, DELAY)

I'm aware there's subscriptionOptions.pollingInterval option for initiate, however since I couldn't find a way to trigger the actual polling loop by using RTK methods it seemed useless in my case.
More context - the reason I'm using the middleware pattern in the first place instead of Hooks is that this API slice is being used in many different components and I don't want to write this polling code everywhere or even for the components to be aware of this.

Have you considered creating a middleware listener that can listen for specific actions to manage the polling subscription? Using the pollingInterval option seems obviously correct to me. It's unclear what is the issue you have using it though. Can you [edit] to clarify the problem and what actual middleware you have tried using/working with?

Thanks @DrewReese. My issue is how do I get access to the new data each poll round - i.e. "polling loop" like I've written in my question. Hence the interval duration by itself isn't helpful. LMK if its clearer now. Regarding the middleware - I'm using the more simple version of configureStore.middleware.

What data do you need to access? Do you mean the data in the result promise the code can await for? It's not clear why you can't use the pollingInterval property and let RTKQ handle the interval for you. Can you [edit] to share your middleware function/code? Maybe it'll become more clear what any problem is if we can see more of what you are trying to do.

All the relevant parts of the middleware are there. Even if I provide pollingInterval option the line const {data, isError, isSuccess} = await resultPromise will be executed only once. I need a way to hook into each iteration of the polling inside RTK. Is there a way to do that in the middleware?

FWIW I have a running "legacy" middleware function that can start/stop a polling interval using the subscriptionOptions.pollingInterval setting, and it all appears to work as I'd expected. Setting a pollingInterval value is what "trigger[s] the actual polling loop" though, so I'm still uncertain what part you are hung up on. I don't know why you'd want to do this the non-React hooks way, it felt like 10 extra unnecessary steps to even the most basic thing. Can you [edit] to clarify the use case and provide a complete [mcve] of the code you are trying to use?
